# Правильный синтаксис при работе с DBF VISUAL fox pro

Tags: c#, dbf

Есть dbf  с fox pro. Пишу на С#.

```
conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=e:\\;Extended Properties=dBASE IV;User ID=;Password=;";

 comm.CommandText = @"SELECT  PRODUKT, NOMER, FEMGN, FEOBS, DATA, TIME FROM ANALIZ  WHERE [DATA] > #01/11/2013# or ([DATA] = #01/11/2013# and [TIME] > #12:40:50#)";
```

проблема что не знаю как обратиться правильно к базе. трабла в том что он сравнивает даты как строки и (*мат*) - у него 29.10.2013 > 01/11/2013

Comment: А если использовать провайдера vfpoledb и фоксовый синтаксис:`
    conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=vfpoledb;Data Source=e:\\;";
    conn.Open();
    OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand(@"SELECT  PRODUKT, NOMER, FEMGN, FEOBS, DATA, TIME FROM ANALIZ  WHERE DATA > DATE(2013,11,1) or (DATA = DATE(2013,11,1))",conn);}`

Какой формат поля TIME - остается только догадываться, ибо в Visual FoxPro, как я помню, нет отдельного формата поля под время.

Comment: как подключиться используя провайдер vfpoledb?

Comment: Я же написал: `
conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=vfpoledb;Data Source=e:\\;";
`
Если вдруг такого нет - скачайте и установите: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14839

Comment: Какая ошибка?

Answer (score 2):

да как вы подключаетесь ?

```
    conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=vfpoledb;Data Source=e:\\;"; conn.Open(); OleDbCommand
                comm = new OleDbCommand(@"SELECT PRODUKT, NOMER, FEMGN, FEOBS, DATA, TIME FROM ANALIZ WHERE DATA > DATE(2013,11,1) or (DATA = DATE(2013,11,1))", conn);
            dt.Load(comm.ExecuteReader());
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

ошибка

Answer (score 0):

У меня так работает с датами и вроде все норм:

```
DateTime d1 = dateTimePicker1.Value;
Form1.zapros = "SELECT date FROM TABLE.DBF WHERE (date >= " +
{^" + d1.ToString("yyyy") + "-" + d1.ToString("MM") + "-" + d1.ToString("dd") + "})" )";
```